# How to avoid repeated updation of the column in the PL/SQL block query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In My query in pl/sql block i wrote the updation of the Q column with resp. to the calucaltion of the F_days columns and after every run its updating the quantity again and again but i want only one time updation.

```
    insert into ISM.TAB
    
    (
            D
            G
            L
            S
            Q
            f_days
        )
    select  D
            G
            L
            S
            Q
            f_DAYS
    from igm.grap;
    
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   
       ' UPDATE ISM.TAB   
 SET Q = (Q / 7)* f_days';
```

Comment: Well, code you posted is **invalid**. What is `f_days`? Why do you use dynamic SQL? There's nothing dynamic in this UPDATE statement, but it lacks in WHERE clause so that's why it updates **all rows** in that table (if that's what you meant to say by "its updating quantity again and again". If not, what does that mean?).

Comment: If all you want is a derived calculated column, use a virtual column instead.

Comment: After inserting the data into ISM.TAB , f_days is the column name which has number as a datatype and Column Q should be calculated acc. to the f_days and then column Q value is update by this formulae but its updating everyone i run the block

Comment: I told you, there's no **WHERE** clause.

Comment: in my code there is where clause which have some conditions but its not related to the updation.

Comment: Just need to avoid repeated updation in this column

Comment: Why execute immediate? Why use dynamic SQL when plain static SQL would do? And no where clause for the update? Meaning you update all rows? To avoid updating again and again you should have an extra indicator column in the table, indicating whether it was updated once or not and use that column in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
 v_updated_flag BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
-- Update the Q column only if it hasn't been updated before
IF NOT v_updated_flag THEN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   
  'UPDATE ISM.TAB   
   SET Q = (Q / 7) * f_days';      
  v_updated_flag := TRUE;
END IF;
END;
```

the v_updated_flag variable is used to keep track of whether the Q column has already been updated. The IF NOT v_updated_flag condition ensures that the update statement is only executed once, and the v_updated_flag := TRUE statement sets the flag to indicate that the update has been completed.

Comment: Nice try, but it doesn't work. Everytime you run this, a new instance of the code block is created and its v_updated_flag is set to false. It doesn't see that there was a former instance which set its own variable to false. What you could do is create a PL/SQL package with a package variable and a package function using this variable. Then a later function call would see the variable value that a former function call set.

Answer (score 0):

It *seems* that you want to copy rows from the grap table to the tab table, but with a modified f_days value. This can be done at the time of insert:

```
insert into ism.tab (d, g, l, s, q, f_days)
  select d, g, l, s, q / 7 * f_days, f_days from igm.grap;
```

Comment: Its not working giving null values

Comment: The only possiblility for the result being null is if either `q` or `f_days` is null. What result do you want in this case? Zero?

Comment: in my query in select Query there is the data for qty and f_days as well but both from different table and i'm using join for that and then inserting the data in ISM.TAB table and after combination and calculation of f_days and qty i'm calculating Q

Comment: With update statement but i'm put this update clause after insert and subquery so its updating the qty again and again but i need only one time updations so what will the query for that ?? i need to put if condition or if i need to put update then where to put upate clause?

Comment: The insert statement adds rows to the table. If you only want to update these rows, then doing it in the insert statement as I am suggesting is by far the best way. If your select query is not as simple as in the example, but contains a join, then run your query (without the insert line), look at the results and find out why you are getting the nulls. Then either decide how to deal with nulls or re-write your query so as not to get them in the first place.